# Stuck at the string number part.. when I enter a string the code returns an error as the input function has been casted as an integer

Tags: python

Question: Create an if-else conditional statement where a user inputs a number and outputs positive, negative, zero or string number.

```
num = input("Input: ")
if num > 0:
   print("Output: Positive")
elif num < 0:
    print("Output: Negative")
elif num == 0:
    print("Output: Zero")
else:
    print("Output: String Number")
```

Comment: `input(...)` *always* returns a string, so you must try to cast it to an integer (using e.g. `try/except`). Afterwards, use `isinstance(...)`. With your snippet, you'll always get `Output: String Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

`num = int(input("Enter Number: "))`

This will ensure that the number the user inputs is an int.

It'll raise an error if the number is a decimal or isn't a number at all.

You can use try and except to catch the error if the string is not a number.

Comment: Thanks, when I do the above the input returns an error when the input is a string. Is there a way to have both work and the "string number" input can be identified?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but you can use a try and except statement to check if the string is a number or just a normal string. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `try except`

```py
try:
    num = int(input("input: "))

    if num > 0:
        print("Output: Positive")
    elif num < 0:
        print("Output: Negative")
    elif num == 0:
        print("Output: Zero")
except:
    print("Output: String Number")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but is there a way to do this where the input can identify if the string is a string number or just a string? Because for the above code, any string I enter will output string number, but the question specifies only string numbers which are "12345" and "five" i think

Comment: `input` will always return `string` type, no matter what you type in the input box. Whether you type `12345` or `five`, it will always return string type. In the above code, if the user input number then it will only execute `try` block otherwise it will only execute `except` block. Execute above code to check the difference